# why does my 2d array display 'x' as 120?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

The idea is to make a 2d array I can put x's and o's in that can be input by the user.
 The following code is what I have.

```
        if(xo.nextInt()== 1){
    System.out.println("You have chosen x");

    for(i =0; i < 6; i++){
        for(j = 0; i < 6; i++){
            System.out.println("Please choose a cell to enter");
            System.out.println(disBoard[i][j] = 'x');
```

I know that I do not have anything asking for a user input for the array at this point. What I want to know is why is it displaying 120 instead of x?

This is how the array was declared:

```
int[][] disBoard;
```

Comment: 120 is the numeric representation of the ASCII character `x`.

Comment: I know you found the answer, but I'm curious why is your second forloop using/incrementing i? Is it suppose to be  for(j = 0; j < 6; j++)?

Comment: You can't put a letter in an array of `int`.  You set `disBoard[i][j] = 'x'` which is simply assigning the `int` value of the `x` character to your array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the array type is `int`, this means that when you store `'x'` to that array, it needs to be converted to an integer. Due to the way characters are represented in Java (as a result of character encoding), `x` is equal to a numeric value of 120.

You can recover the character value by *casting*:

```
char characterVal = (char)(disBoard[i][j]);
```

Or, you can change the array to be a `char[][]` which would allow you to store characters.

Comment: Thanks I just realised its the value of 120  :) I never knew how to recover the character value though thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3):

P̶r̶o̶b̶a̶b̶l̶y̶  you've declared `int[][] disBoard` and 120 is the `int` value of `'x'`. Just change the declaration to `char[][] disBoard`.

Comment: "probably"? He states he declared it this way.

Comment: @hexafraction I don't see any part in the post where OP states `int[][] disBoard`. Do you?

Comment: The last sentence, "The array type is int"

Comment: @hexafraction last line of the OP.

Comment: @hexafraction fixed both question and answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just looked up ascii table and realised its the ascii code for x.

Comment: `char` are not ASCII but UTF-16.